# Modular ReactJS Application - Confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, frontend, single-page-application

For now we have everything we need to build full SPA (routing: react-router, async: sagas, state: redux etc.). Architecture and the process of creating that kind of app is straightforward for me but the problem begins when i need to create website that has just couple of independent modules and they need to comunicate to each other. For example on Facebook there is several places to inform user that he has new message or when we click on the user from the users list new chatbox is created. Using React dev tool we can see that new independent components are created. In the SPA there is one root Component and whole content is inside it. So my question is how to solve that kind of problem ? i.e. create small modules and provide communication between them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Redux. Redux allows you use a global store, that works like React Component. You can update the global store from anywhere and whenever store updated, redux will update another components.

[Redux on Github](https://github.com/reactjs/redux)

Comment: Redux store is attached to Provider which is connected to some root Component so this is not the case because in this approach everything must to be inside this provider i want to have several non-hierarchical modules instead. Imagine that you have site where you can bet some sport events and for simplicity let's assume that we have user panel that stores current user balance and simple box where you can select event and bet. Site is not SPA(everything else is rendered by server) you just want to use ReactJS for this two things i.e. update user account balance and bet events. This is a problem

Comment: But what is the problem in using one global parent? If you don't want to use global store, tell me what's the difference between `window` global variable and global store, in both case you have a common and single global parent.

Comment: There are only two differences between them. 
1) Redux implements the `Observer` design pattern, unlike `window` object.
2) Redux Store is an "immutable" object.

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding here. For example in code below
`<body>
 <div id="react-module></div>
 <div>some content rendered by server...</div>
 [more content...]
 <div id="react-module2"></div>
 ...
</body>`

there are two 'modules' that i want to create in ReactJS and they need to comunicate to each other somehow. What would you do to achieve this ? I don't want to create rest of page using ReactJS.